# Give better error message than just 'An error occurred while adding this comment'

Tags: feature-request, comments, error-message

I got this error while posting a comment:

> 'An error occurred while adding this comment'.

Let me know why there was an error and what I should do:

- Try again later?
- Refresh the page?
- Edit my comment?

What?

Comment: I mean, if an error occurred while adding a comment you should try posting it later since an error occurred just now. You can try and refresh the page - It might help. But I don't need a notification instructing me that, it's just something you do naturally

Comment: Yeah I know what to do. I copied my comment and refreshed the page, posted it  and it worked. My post here is about showing more meaningful messages. It's not about .. Oh I'm lost now.. I need help.  I noticed most programmers don't bother. They display generic messages and let the user deal with it. It's the user's problem.

Comment: 'An error occurred while adding this comment' should seem embarrassing unless it's very rare.  Some things are unforeseeable, but I'm surprised that the only response to this question is a single comment--not even an answer--essentially implying that a cryptic error message isn't really cryptic.  Even if that's one user's view, it shouldn't be the last word.  Oh well.